# Scraping website and print them via routers

Tags: beginner, web-scraping, go, api, rest

I've been working on a personal project for a while which simply extracts some information from a website and save them as JSON files. Then I've decided to move those scraping functionalities to the server and write simple js application which sends `GET` requests to extract that information.

Before I start, I'd like to mention that I've never written `Go` code before and this is the first time that I'm working with `REST`.

Here's my project tree:

```
├── api
│   └── server
│       ├── handlers
│       │   ├── generic.go
│       │   ├── info.go
│       │   └── search.go
│       └── router
│           └── router.go
├── cmd
│   └── app.go
├── models
│   └── mangadex.go
├── pkg
│   └── parser
│       └── mangadex
│           ├── helpers.go
│           └── mangadex.go
```

models file:

```
package models

type Base struct {
    URL   string `json:"url"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Stamp string `json:"stamp"`
}

// Extracted information
type MangaData struct {
    Image        string         `json:img`
    AltNames     string         `json:alterNames`
    Author       string         `json:author`
    Genres       string         `json:genres`
    Status       string         `json:status`
    Description  string         `json:description`
    ChapterLinks *[]ChapterInfo `json:"chapterLinks"`
}

// Chapter informations
type ChapterInfo struct {
    Name string `json:"chapterName"`
    Link string `json:"link"`
    ChNo int    `json:"chno"`
}

// Chapter's page information.
type ImgLinks struct {
    PageNo   int    `json:"pageno"`
    PageLink string `json:"pagelink"`
}
```

mangadex.go:

```
package mangadex

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/me/testProject/models"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

// constants urls
const baseUrl = "https://mangadex.org"
const baseSearchUrl = "https://mangadex.org/quick_search/"

// Search manga with given name.
// Shows all of the mangas that contains that name
func SearchManga(name string) *[]models.Base {

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    url := baseSearchUrl + name
    fmt.Println(url)
    collections := []models.Base{}

    // Scraping the body which contains the series of mangas
    c.OnHTML("#search_manga table.table.table-striped tbody tr td "+
        "a.manga_title", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        temp := models.Base{}
        temp.URL = e.Attr("href")
        temp.Title = e.Attr("title")
        temp.Stamp = time.Now().String()
        collections = append(collections, temp)
    })

    // Set max Parallelism and introduce a Random Delay
    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        Parallelism: 2,
        RandomDelay: 5 * time.Second,
    })

    c.Visit(url)
    c.Wait()
    return &collections
}

// Extracting unique manga chapter ids. '/chapter/{uniqueId}'
func getChapterLinks(url string) *[]models.ChapterInfo {

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    coll := []models.ChapterInfo{}
    url = url + "/chapters/"
    lastpage := getPageNumber(url)
    lastpageInt, err := strconv.Atoi(lastpage)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Cannot convert lastpage to int")
    }
    c.OnHTML("#content", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        ci := models.ChapterInfo{}
        e.ForEach(".table-responsive table tbody tr",
            func(j int, e *colly.HTMLElement) {
                lang := e.ChildAttr("img", "title")
                // mangadex supports multiple languages but
                // we only interested in English chapters
                // so this filters the language
                if lang == "English" {
                    ci.Link = e.ChildAttr("a", "href")
                    ch := e.ChildAttr("a", "data-chapter-num")
                    ci.ChNo, _ = strconv.Atoi(ch)
                    ci.Name = e.ChildText("a")

                    coll = append(coll, ci)
                }
            })

    })
    for i := 1; i <= lastpageInt; i++ {
        c.Visit(url + strconv.Itoa(i))
    }
    c.Wait()
    return &coll
}

// Manga page of the mangadex contains: Manga img, alternative titles of the manga,
// Author(s), genres, status description and some not important ones.
// Also the available chapters of course.
func HarvestData(path string) *[]models.MangaData {
    url := baseUrl + path

    fmt.Println(url)
    collections := []models.MangaData{}
    temp := models.MangaData{}
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    c.OnHTML("#content", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        temp.Image = e.ChildAttr(".row.edit .col-sm-3 img", "src")
        vr := getChapterLinks(url)
        temp.ChapterLinks = vr
        // 0: Alternative Names
        // 1: Author
        // 2: Artist
        // 3: Genres
        // 5: Status
        // 7: Description
        // 8: Related
        e.ForEach(".row.edit .col-sm-9 tbody tr",
            func(i int, el *colly.HTMLElement) {
                switch i {
                case 0:
                    temp.AltNames = el.ChildText("td")
                case 1:
                    temp.Author = el.ChildText("td")
                case 3:
                    temp.Genres = el.ChildText("td")
                case 5:
                    temp.Status = el.ChildText("td")
                case 7:
                    temp.Description = el.ChildText("td")
                }

            })
        // usually there are couple manga pages
        // thats why I think separating the chapter implementation
        // would be good.
        collections = append(collections, temp)
    })

    c.Visit(url)
    c.Wait()
    /* fmt.Println(test2) */
    return &collections
}

// Each page of the cahpter
func Pages(url string) *[]models.ImgLinks {

    url = baseUrl + url
    fmt.Println(url)
    lp := LastPage(url)
    imgData := []models.ImgLinks{}

    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        Parallelism: 2,
        RandomDelay: 5 * time.Second,
    })

    c.OnHTML("#content .images img", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        dt := models.ImgLinks{}
        dt.PageNo, _ = strconv.Atoi(e.Attr("data-page"))
        dt.PageLink = e.Attr("src")

        imgData = append(imgData, dt)
    })

    for i := 1; i <= lp; i++ {
        c.Visit(url + strconv.Itoa(i))
    }
    c.Wait()
    return &imgData
}
```

helpers.go:

```
// Since Mangadex has horrible design, I need to parse each and every tag separately like
// find available pages in pagination, how many pages available in the chap
// I moved those functionalities here as 'helpers'.

package mangadex

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

// Returns to the last page number of the chapter.
func LastPage(url string) int {
    var lp int
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        Parallelism: 2,
        RandomDelay: 5 * time.Second,
    })

    c.OnHTML("#jump_page option", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        dta := e.Attr("value")
        lp, _ = strconv.Atoi(dta)

    })

    c.Visit(url)
    c.Wait()
    return lp
}

// Returns to the last page of the available chapter's list.
// TODO: What happens pagination have 10 pages but shows only 5 of them ?
func getPageNumber(url string) string {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("mangadex.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )
    var pageNum string

    c.OnHTML("li.paging a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        pageNum = e.Attr("href")
    })

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("err happnd")
    })
    c.Visit(url)
    c.Wait()
    pageArr := strings.Split(pageNum, "/")
    if len(pageNum) == 0 {
        pageNum = "1"
        return pageNum
    }
    pageNum = pageArr[5]
    fmt.Println(pageNum)
    return pageNum
}
```

router.go:

```
package router

import (
    "github.com/me/testProject/api/server/handlers"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

// Initialises the routers
func Init() *httprouter.Router {

    // Router
    r := httprouter.New()

    // Creating Root
    r.GET("/", handlers.HandleRoot)

    // Searching manga handlers
    r.GET("/manga", handlers.HandleManga)
    r.GET("/manga/:name", handlers.HandleSearchManga)

    // Information page handlers
    r.GET("/info", handlers.HandleInfo)
    r.GET("/info/manga", handlers.HandleNullRoute)
    r.GET("/info/manga/:id", handlers.HandleNullRoute)
    r.GET("/info/manga/:id/:title", handlers.HandleInfoPage)

    // Chapter handlers
    r.GET("/info/chapter", handlers.HandleNullRoute)
    r.GET("/info/chapter/:id", handlers.HandleImages)

    return r

}
```

handlers:

package handlers

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/me/testProject/pkg/parser/mangadex"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
)

func HandleManga(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,
    ps httprouter.Params) {

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "404 Not Found")
}

func HandleSearchManga(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request,
    ps httprouter.Params) {

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    searchedMangaName := ps.ByName("name")
    // data is []base, now we have to marshalize it
    data := mangadex.SearchManga(searchedMangaName)

    wr, _ := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", " ")
    w.Write(wr)
    //just printing to the console
    val := string(wr)
    fmt.Println(val)

}
```

Rest of the handlers, `generic and info` have similar implementations, that's why I'm going to omit them.
I would appreciate all criticism relevant to code, style, best practices and so forth.